# Javacc avoiding cycle

Tags: javacc

I have a cycle in my grammar which produces the following error message

```
Error: Line 395, Column 1: Left recursion detected:
 "PostfixExpression... --> FunctionCall... --> FunctionCallOrMethod... --> FunctionCallGeneric... --> FunctionCallHeaderWithParameters... --> FunctionCallHeader... --> FunctionIdentifier... --> PostfixExpression..."
Detected 1 errors and 1 warnings.
```

From the following grammar

```
void PostfixExpression() : {}
{
/* recursive version:
  PrimaryExpression()
| PostfixExpression() <LEFT_BRACKET> IntegerExpression() <RIGHT_BRACKET>
| FunctionCall()
| PostfixExpression() <DOT> FieldSelection()
| PostfixExpression() <INC_OP>
| PostfixExpression() <DEC_OP>
*/
  PrimaryExpression() [PostfixExpressionPrime()]
| FunctionCall() [PostfixExpressionPrime()]
}

void PostfixExpressionPrime() : {}
{
  <LEFT_BRACKET> IntegerExpression() <RIGHT_BRACKET> [PostfixExpressionPrime()]
| <DOT> FieldSelection() [PostfixExpressionPrime()]
| <INC_OP> [PostfixExpressionPrime()]
| <DEC_OP> [PostfixExpressionPrime()]
}

void FunctionCall() : {}
{
  FunctionCallOrMethod()
}

void FunctionCallOrMethod() : {}
{
  FunctionCallGeneric()
}

void FunctionCallGeneric() : {}
{
  FunctionCallHeaderWithParameters() <RIGHT_PAREN>
| FunctionCallHeaderNoParameters() <RIGHT_PAREN>
}

void FunctionCallHeaderWithParameters() : {}
{
/* recursive version:
  FunctionCallHeader() AssignmentExpression()
| FunctionCallHeaderWithParameters() <COMMA> AssignmentExpression()
*/
  FunctionCallHeader() AssignmentExpression() [FunctionCallHeaderWithParametersPrime()]
}

void FunctionCallHeaderWithParametersPrime() : {}
{
  <COMMA> AssignmentExpression() [FunctionCallHeaderWithParametersPrime()]
}

void FunctionCallHeader() : {}
{
  FunctionIdentifier() <LEFT_PAREN>
}

void FunctionIdentifier() : {}
{
  TypeSpecifier()
| PostfixExpression()
}
```

Is there some kind of algorithm I can apply to eliminate this problem in general? If not, how do I do it in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar grammar

```
PostfixEx --> FuncCall [PostfixEx'] | Primary [PostfixEx']
Primary --> ID
PostfixEx' --> "++" [PostfixEx']
FuncCall --> FuncID "(" ")"
FuncID --> PostfixEx | TypeSpecifier
TypeSpecifier --> "int"
```

So for example "ID ++ ( )" is ok, as is "int ( ) ++", but "int ++" is not allowed

Here is one thing you can do.

(a) Eliminate FuncID

```
PostfixEx --> FuncCall [PostfixEx'] | Primary [PostfixEx']
Primary --> ID
PostfixEx' --> "++" [PostfixEx']
FuncCall --> (PostfixEx | TypeSpecifier) "(" ")"
TypeSpecifier --> "int"
```

(b) Distribute FuncCall

```
PostfixEx --> FuncCall [PostfixEx'] | Primary [PostfixEx']
Primary --> ID
PostfixEx' --> "++" [PostfixEx']
FuncCall --> PostfixEx "(" ")" | TypeSpecifier"(" ")"
TypeSpecifier --> "int"
```

(c) Eliminate FuncCall

```
PostfixEx --> (PostfixEx "(" ")" | TypeSpecifier"(" ")")  [PostfixEx']
             | Primary [PostfixEx']
Primary --> ID
PostfixEx' --> "++" [PostfixEx']
TypeSpecifier --> "int"
```

(c) Distribute PostfixEx

```
PostfixEx --> PostfixEx "(" ")" [PostfixEx']
             | TypeSpecifier"(" ")"  [PostfixEx']
             | Primary [PostfixEx']
Primary --> ID
PostfixEx' --> "++" [PostfixEx']
TypeSpecifier --> "int"
```

(d) Left recursion removal A -> A w | x  ==> A --> x (w)*

```
PostfixEx -->  ( TypeSpecifier"(" ")"  [PostfixEx'] | Primary [PostfixEx'] )
               ("(" ")" [PostfixEx'])*
Primary --> ID
PostfixEx' --> "++" [PostfixEx']
TypeSpecifier --> "int"
```

(e) Distribute PostfixEx

```
PostfixEx -->    TypeSpecifier"(" ")"  [PostfixEx'] ("(" ")" [PostfixEx'])*
               | Primary [PostfixEx'] ("(" ")" [PostfixEx'])*
Primary --> ID
PostfixEx' --> "++" [PostfixEx']
TypeSpecifier --> "int"
```

(e) Create nonterminal PostfixExOperators

```
PostfixEx -->    TypeSpecifier"(" ")"  PostFixOperators
               | Primary PostFixOperators
Primary --> ID
PostFixOperators --> [PostfixEx'] ("(" ")" [PostfixEx'])*   
PostfixEx' --> "++" [PostfixEx']        
TypeSpecifier --> "int"
```

(f) Create nonterminal PostFixOperand

```
PostfixEx -->    PostFixOperand  PostFixOperators
PostFixOperand --> Primary | TypeSpecifier "(" ")"
Primary --> ID
PostfixEx' --> "++" [PostfixEx']
PostFixOperators --> [PostfixEx'] ("(" ")" [PostfixEx'])*           
TypeSpecifier --> "int"
```

(g) Clean up PostFixOperators

```
PostFixEx --> PostFixOperand PostFixOperators
PostFixOperand --> Primary | TypeSpecifier "(" ")"
Primary --> ID
PostFixOperators --> ( "++" | "(" ")" )*
TypeSpecifier --> "int"
```

Comment: I inlined everything until the function was a trivial case of left-recursion, then factored as usual. Thanks again!